# Is there a way by default to require ALL words in full text searching?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, boolean-search

I'm trying to find a way to make it so when users do a search that by default ALL words are required.

This seemed easy enough at the beginning, just break the words up and add a `+` sign to the start of each word; however when you start to try and implement the other operators it get's complicated.

This is what I have so far..

```
function prepareKeywords($str) {

    // Remove any + signs since we add them ourselves
    // Also remove any operators we don't allow
    // We don't allow some operators as they would have no use in the search since we don't order our results by relevance
    $str = str_replace(array('+','~','<','>'), '', $str);

    // Remove anything more than once space
    $str = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $str);

    // Now break up words into parts
    $str = str_getcsv($str, ' ', '"');

    // Now prepend a + sign to the front of each word

    foreach ($ks as $key => $word) {

        // First we check to make sure the start of the word doesn't already contain an operator before we add the + sign to the start

        if (in_array($word{0}, array('-','<','>','~'))) {

        } else {
            $ks[$key] = '+' . $word;   
        }

    }

    // Now put word back to string
    //$ks = implode(' ', $ks);    

}
```

As you can see it only gets so far at the moment, respects quoted strings, but then I start thinking about not breaking up `()` as well, and then what if that contains nested double quotes or vice versa.... it starts getting very hairy.

So I'm trying to figure out if there is a way that I can do what I want without messing with the string and just making all words required by default UNLESS the user specifically negates them with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can make use of preg_match() and \b in the pattern as the word boundary?

You search terms can then be split with something like

```
preg_match_all('/\b(.*)\b/', $matches);
```

I might be on the wrong thinking as it's late here, but it might give you something to go on

Comment: Ah, it was late. Worth a try :)